# WHat is the log likelihood function for the Pareto Distribution?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

Given the Pareto distribution, $f(x_i;\alpha, \delta) = \frac {\theta \alpha^\theta} {x_i^{\theta+1}}$ $x_i \gt \alpha; \theta \ge 0$ how do I write the log likelihood function, which I understand to be of the form $P(y=1\mid X)$, so for the pareto distribution would I write, $\ln P(y=1\mid \frac {\theta \alpha^\theta} {x_i^{\theta+1}})$?

Answer (score 1):

If the two parameters are $\delta$ and $\alpha,$ then I wonder what $\theta$ is doing there. I will assume that instead you meant
$$
f(x_i\mid \alpha,\delta) = \frac{\delta \alpha^\delta}{x_i^{\delta + 1}} \quad \text{for } x_i>\alpha.
$$
The joint density for $n$ independent random variables with this distribution is
$$
\prod_{i=1}^n \frac{\delta \alpha^\delta}{x_i^{\delta + 1}} \quad\text{for } x_1,\ldots,x_n>\alpha.
$$
The likelihood function is that expression as a function of $\alpha$ and $\delta$ with $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ fixed. Thus it is
\begin{align}
L(\alpha,\delta) & = \begin{cases} \prod_{i=1}^n \frac{\delta \alpha^\delta}{x_i^{\delta + 1}} & \text{if } \alpha \ge \min\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}, \\
0 & \text{if } \alpha< \min.
\end{cases} \\[12pt]
& = \begin{cases}
\delta^n \alpha^{n\delta} \left/ \,\prod_{i=1}^n x_i^{\delta+1} \right. & \text{if } \alpha\ge\min, \\ 0 & \text{if } \alpha<\min.
\end{cases}
\end{align}
Its logarithm is
$$
\ell(\alpha,\delta) = n\log\delta - n\delta\log\alpha - (\delta+1) \sum_{i=1}^n \log x_i \text{ for } \alpha\ge\min\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}.
$$
I don't know what that thing you're calling $y$ is.

Notice that this gets bigger as $\alpha$ gets smaller, so the value of $\alpha$ that maximizes this is the smallest possible value of $\alpha,$ namely $\widehat\alpha = \min\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}.$